# Conexión con servidores STARTTLS

Tags: java, android

Estoy tratando de conectar mi aplicación con servidores que tienen encriptación STARTTLS con android-mail 1.5.6 (un java-mail "amiguito" de Android LOL)

Ayer probé con un BLU LIFE PLAY 2 Android 4.4.2 (clon Gionee Elife 3 con AmigOS 4.4.2) y me funcionaba bien. Hoy hago las pruebas una AVD con And 4.0 y todo OK, pero en LG K10 con Android 6.0.1 de LG y es donde tengo problemas

aqui van los códigos

```
...
enum Sec{SSL_TLS, STARTTLS, NONE}

...   
public Session getSession(String user, String pass, String host, String port, String provider, Sec sec){
Properties props = new Properties();
    switch (sec){
        case SSL_TLS:
            props.put("mail."+provider+".socketFactory.port", port);
            props.put("mail."+provider+"s.socketFactory.port", port);
            props.put("mail."+inProvider+".socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            props.put("mail."+inProvider+"s.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            break;
        case STARTTLS:
            props.put("mail."+provider+".starttls.enable", "true");
            props.put("mail."+provider+"s.starttls.enable", "true");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    if (inCerts){
        MailSSLSocketFactory sf = null;
        try{
            sf = new MailSSLSocketFactory();
        }catch (GeneralSecurityException e){
            utils.serr(e);
        }
        sf.setTrustAllHosts(true);
        props.put("mail."+provider+".ssl.socketFactory", sf);
        props.put("mail."+provider+".tls.socketFactory", sf);
        props.put("mail."+provider+"s.ssl.socketFactory", sf);
        props.put("mail."+provider+"s.tls.socketFactory", sf);
        props.put("mail."+provider+".socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        props.put("mail."+provider+"s.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    }

    try
    {
        //Connect to the server
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
return session;

...

String user="myuser";
String user="mypass";
String host="mail.host.com";
String port="143";

Sec sec=STARTTLS;
String provider="imap";

Session session = getSession(user, pass, host, port, provider, sec);
Store store     = session.getStore(provider);
        if (port==null)
            store.connect(host, user, pass);
        else
            store.connect(host, Integer.parseInt(port), user, pass);
Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        inbox.close(false);
        store.close();
```

el error con imap

```
com.sun.mail.ProtocolException: STARTTLS failure
javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake terminated:
```

Comment: Pudiera ser que no esté aceptando certificados no conocidos?

Comment: Creo que he encontrado el problema y es relacionado con algo como que Android 6.0 en adelante no aceptan certificados no VALIDOS? http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLEngine.html https://github.com/iiordanov/remote-desktop-clients/issues/57 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33546496/sslhandshakeexception-sslprotocolexception-with-android-6-marshmallow